# Get/parse a Google Spreadsheet as Json

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get/parse a Google Spreadsheet as JSON? I know the library API exists, but is there already some cooked-up (abstract) solution or should it be written for a specific worksheet every time?

Comment: you can download as CSV then convert the CSV to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Would this info help: http://blog.pamelafox.org/2013/06/exporting-google-spreadsheet-as-json.html

The above links to this gist: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/1878143